# Trying to print values in multidimensional array to form as presets values

Tags: php, mysql, templates, controller

I'm currently working on a project where my current goal is to print information about the specific user on the final checkout form inputs.

First off I gather the information of the specific user through a public function:

```
public function getUserAddress($dbh)
{
    $sql = "SELECT street, zip, city FROM address WHERE user_id=:user";
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':user', $this->uid);
    $stmt->execute();
    $userAddress = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $this->userAddress = $userAddress;
    return $this->userAddress;
}
```

Then I store the information in a variable I call $userAddress

```
$userAddress = $user->getUserAddress($dbh);
```

Since the user has two addresses, both with a "Street", "City" & "Zip" I'm storing both arrays in $templateData. This way I can specify what index should be printed out in which input tag instead of having to create a new function for each slot.

```
$templateData['user']['address'] = $userAdress['street']." ".$userAddress['city']." ".$userAddress['zip'];
```

However, printing these out seems near impossible. When I var_dump 
    $templateData['user']['address']
I only seem to be getting 2 empty strings and nothing else.

This is just code from my Checkout.controller but somehow the information doesn't seem to be found in my template page. All routes and includes are correct so dw about that.

I'm quite new to all this so I'd appreciate any help I can get!

Image of how the information should be presented https://gyazo.com/40fa06832207bd785ee038af4962bb1e

So in this case: "Postort" = "City" & "Gatuadress" = "Street"

Answer (score 0):

[`PDO::fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) will return an array of associative arrays; so to access the individual elements you need something like:

```
 $userAdress[0]['street']." ".$userAddress[0]['city']." ".$userAddress[0]['zip']
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried doing that. Even added another since the address i split into a "Primary" and "Secondary" address. One line, identical to the one you wrote and one with [1] instead of [0] on each of 'em. Though when I dump it all out the entire address including Street, Zip & City are all in one string and since I want to seperate them it becomes even harder.

Comment: For the code you've given this is definitely the right way to access the values. I'm not sure what you mean when you say they're all in one string? That's what this code does... perhaps you can edit your post with some more detail of what you want the output to be?

Comment: Yeah I've edited my post and added an image on how I want the info to be presented. There is obviously som issues in my code which prevents me to split the values accross multiple inputs. How would you go about this?

Comment: It seems you probably want something like `foreach ($userAddress as $address) $templateData['user']['address'][] = $address;` then when you come to output the data into the form you would use (e.g. for Postort) `echo $templateData['user']['address'][0]['city'];`. I'm afraid without seeing a lot more of your code it's hard to offer more suggestions than that...

Answer (score 0):

I could alaways define every single one of them specifically although it seems far fetched. Something like this:

```
 $templateData['user']['address'][0]['street'] = $userAddress[0]['street'];
 $templateData['user']['address'][0]['city'] = $userAddress[0]['city'];
 $templateData['user']['address'][0]['zip'] = $userAddress[0]['zip'];

 $templateData['user']['address'][1]['street'] = $userAddress[1]['street'];
 $templateData['user']['address'][1]['city'] = $userAddress[1]['city'];
 $templateData['user']['address'][1]['zip'] = $userAddress[1]['zip'];
```

I'm basically looking for another solution which doesn't require so much repetition.

Comment: You can replace that code with `foreach ($userAddress as $address) $templateData['user']['address'][] = $address;`